# Dart2JS - Use Strict

Tags: dart

Why does the Dart2JS compiler not generate code that includes "use strict" at the top of each of the script files?  If all generated Javascript code is valid ECMA5 code, then shouldn't the compiler automatically add the "use strict" command?

**Update:**
Apparently this is already being tracked by [issue 1686.](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1686)

Answer (score 0):

To formally answer, this feature request can be found in [issue 1686](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1686) in the [Dart issue tracker](http://dartbug.com).

As for why, there hasn't been much demand for it and the dart2js team has been focused on language conformance and performance.